# Optimal Data structure for queries involved rectangles and cartesian coordinates

Tags: data-structures, optimization, computational-geometry, trees

What data structure would be optimal in terms of time and space for the following usecase:
Given information about rectangles in the form of-            {rectangle_id,left_bottom_corner_x, left_bottom_corner_y, right_top_corner_x, right_top_corner_y}.

I need to use a structure which will answer the following queries:

1.) which rectangles among the given rectangles overlap with each other, if the query asks about a rectangle with ID 1, I need to output the rectangles it is overlapping
2.) given a point(x,y) which rectangles is it inside (for eg a point (0,1) may be inside a rectangle with coordinates : (0,0) and (2,2) of the bottom left and top right corners respectively)
3.) which rectangles abut it(are adjacent to it/touch it)

I have already used a 2d matrix but it is quite slow for large datasets (for 1000 coordinates it has a running time of 16 seconds). I have not considered any other data structures yet.
Below I have attached code to my naive solution:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1LPRpg61ti95KlVIehEBQJWD_o7ZUGNJY?usp=sharing

Comment: I do not have specific running time measurements and optimal in the sense of worst case time as well as space/memory usage

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

Comment: Welcome to [computational geometry](/tags/computational-geometry/info).

Comment: @Pseudonym could you please clarify a little more

Comment: @fat_gladiator17 R-trees and their variants are standard spatial index data structures for performing queries such as this.